# FAQ with search input using Bootstrap - hiding accordion by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to create FAQ using Bootstrap with search bar and accordion below. What I need to do is to hide all answers by default and show filtered results only if I type some text and hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or click the search icon. They should be also hidden when I clear input field.

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnczk51y/2/)

I was trying to add a function that removes and adds a CSS class when I hit the hotkey but its not working, it adds/removes the class always when I hit the ENTER key.

```
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I have about 50 FAQ questions so this is the reason I need to hide them all by default and keep hidden most of them when input text is not matching.

Comment: The code says `e.keyCode == 13` which compares the key to the enter key. Is this just about finding the ascii code for whatever your hotkey is? Also, how does the question title fit into this? Is it about hiding everything, which you seem to have accomplished, or the key?

Comment: Hey. No **e.keyCode == 13** (enter key) is OK now, it search words good. But now I need to hide answers (accordion) by default and show them ONLY if I start searching. I have more than 50 answers so it is to many to display them by default. I need to hide them and display filtered results affter clik search or hit enter key.